# Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array

Tags: php, wordpress

tengo este error que viene del tema que estoy usando en mi sitio web pero realmente no sé como resolverlo.

El log es el siguiente:

> Se ha producido un error del tipo E_ERROR en la línea 237 del archivo /home/uarquice/public_html/wp-content/themes/massive-dynamic/lib/admin/data/sources.php. Mensaje de error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in /home/uarquice/public_html/wp-content/themes/massive-dynamic/lib/admin/data/sources.php:237
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/uarquice/public_html/wp-content/themes/massive-dynamic/lib/admin/classes/control/fieldmulti.php(35): vp_get_fontawesome_icons('')
> #1 /home/uarquice/public_html/wp-content/themes/massive-dynamic/lib/admin/classes/control/field/fontawesome.php(22): VP_Control_FieldMulti->_basic_make(Array)
> #2 /home/uarquice/public_html/wp-content/themes/massive-dynamic/lib/admin/classes/metabox.php(356): VP_Control_Field_Fontawesome::withArray(Array)
> #3 /home/uarquice/public_html/wp-content/themes/massive-dynamic/lib/admin/classes/metabox.php(415): VP_Metabox->_enfactor_field(Array, Object(VP_Metabox), true)
> #4 /home/uarquice/public_html/wp-content/themes/massive-dynamic/lib/admin/classes/metabox.php(434): VP_Metabox->_enfactor_group(Array, Object(VP_Metabox), true)
> #5 /home/uarquice/public_html/wp-content/themes/massive-dynamic/lib/admin/classes/metabox

La función a la que hace referencia es:

```
function vp_get_fontawesome_icons()
{
    // scrape list of icons from fontawesome css
    if( false === ( $icons  = get_transient( 'vp_fontawesome_icons' ) ) )
    {
        $pattern = '/\.(icon-(?:\w+(?:-)?)+):before\s*{\s*content/';
        $subject = wp_remote_get(
                pixflow_path_combine(PIXFLOW_THEME_CSS_URI,'iconfonts.min.css'),
                array(
                        "timeout" => 90,
                        "sslverify" => false
                )
        );
        $subject = $subject['body'];

        preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

        $icons = array();

        foreach($matches as $match)
        {
            $icons[] = array('value' => $match[1], 'label' => $match[1]);
        }
        set_transient( 'vp_fontawesome_icons', $icons, 60 * 60 * 24 );
    }

    return $icons;
}
```

La línea 237 a la que el log hace referencia en el código es **$subject = $subject['body'];**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Según la documentación](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/#return), `wp_remote_get` puede devolverte un array o un objeto `WP_Error` si ocurre un fallo:

> **Return**
>
> (`array`|`WP_Error`) The response or `WP_Error` on failure.

El mensaje: `Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array` indica claramente que en ese contexto, la llamada devolvió error, por tanto, no puedes hacer esto:

```
    $subject = $subject['body'];
```

Tienes que verificar primero qué es `$subject` para operar con él.

Por ejemplo:

```
if ( is_array( $subject ) && ! is_wp_error( $subject ) ) {
    //Aquí puedes hacer todas tus operaciones con $subject
} else {
    //$subject no es un array, hacer lo que debas hacer en este caso
}
```

Comment: Completamente acertivo, muchas gracias A. Cedano